# Google combo chart - Intervals with multiple bars and lines

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, multiple-columns, intervals

I am trying to create a combo chart with multiple bars and lines. As the lines are an average, I want to add min and max error bars too. Google refer to these as 'intervals'.

The problem is that the lines align to the centre of bars (between the two, which is fine) but the intervals for those lines seem to align with the first bar instead. See my example.
[Example of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llKXk.png)

My code is as below. Any help much appreciated! Perhaps this is a Google bug? Or is there an alignment parameter I have missed maybe?

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/tpygott/43fs9x1r/)

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

  function drawVisualization() {
    // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Week'); // Implicit domain label col.

    data.addColumn('number', 'A average'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}); // annotationText col.

    data.addColumn('number', 'A rolling average'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});  // interval role col.
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});  // interval role col.

    data.addColumn('number', 'B average'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
    data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}); // annotationText col.

    data.addColumn('number', 'B 4wk average'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});  // interval role col.
    data.addColumn({type: 'number', role: 'interval'});  // interval role col.
    data.addRows([ 
      ['1 (01/03/17)', 0.1, 'A1', 0.2, 0.19, 0.21, 0.20, 'A2', 0.67, 0.66, 0.68],  
      ['2 (08/03/17)', 0.23, 'B1', 0.90, 0.89, 0.91, 0.76, 'B2', 0.43, 0.42, 0.44],  
      ['3 (15/03/17)', 0.10, 'C1', 0.65, 0.63, 0.66, 0.34, 'C2', 0.89, 0.88, 0.90],  
      ['4 (22/03/17)', 0.22, 'D1', 0.20, 0.19, 0.21, 0.23, 'D2', 0.43, 0.42, 0.44]
      //  ['1 (01/03/17)',10,  2, 11,  'A'],
        //  ['2 (08/03/17)',  23, 20, 25,  'B'],
        //  ['3 (15/03/17)',  1,  0.95,  1.15,  'C'],
        //  ['4 (22/03/17)', 22, 20, 30, 'D']
    ]);


    var options = {
      title: 'Test',
      vAxis: {
        title: '% average',
        format: '# %'
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Week number (week commencing)'
      },
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {
        1: {type: 'line'},
        3: {type: 'line'}
      },
      intervals: {
        style: 'boxes'
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**looks like a bug** -- when intervals are used with more than one column (bar) series,
intervals align properly otherwise...

one option would be to move them manually, when the chart's `'ready'` event fires

however, the chart will send the intervals back to their original location,
anytime there is *interactivity*, such as *hover* or *select*

as such, a `MutationObserver` can be used to know when *interactivity* has occurred,
in order to set the desired location of the intervals

---

see following working snippet,
the intervals are moved to new x-coordinates when the `'ready'` event fires,
the new x-coordinates are then saved and re-applied when *interactivity* occurs...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawVisualization,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Week'); // Implicit domain label col.

  data.addColumn('number', 'A average'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
  data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'}); // annotationText col.

  data.addColumn('number', 'A rolling average'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
  data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'interval'});  // interval role col.
  data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'interval'});  // interval role col.

  data.addColumn('number', 'B average'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
  data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'}); // annotationText col.

  data.addColumn('number', 'B 4wk average'); // Implicit series 1 data col.
  data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'interval'});  // interval role col.
  data.addColumn({type:'number', role:'interval'});  // interval role col.
  data.addRows([
    ['1 (01/03/17)',0.10, 'A1', 0.20,0.19,0.21, 0.20, 'A2', 0.67,0.66,0.68],
    ['2 (08/03/17)',0.23, 'B1', 0.90,0.89,0.91, 0.76, 'B2', 0.43,0.42,0.44],
    ['3 (15/03/17)',0.10, 'C1', 0.65,0.63,0.66, 0.34, 'C2', 0.89,0.88,0.90],
    ['4 (22/03/17)',0.22, 'D1', 0.20,0.19,0.21, 0.23, 'D2', 0.43,0.42,0.44]
  ]);

  var options = {
    title : 'Test',
    vAxis: {title: '% average',format:'# %'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Week number (week commencing)'},
    height: 600,
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      1: {type: 'line'},
      3: {type: 'line'}
    },
    tooltip: {trigger: 'both'},
    intervals: {style: 'boxes'},
    width: 900
  };

  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(chartDiv);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function () {
    getIntervals().forEach(function (rect, index) {
      rect.setAttribute('x', xCoords[index]);
    });
  });

  var xCoords = {};
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    getIntervals().forEach(function (rect, index) {
      xCoords[index] = parseFloat(rect.getAttribute('x')) + 22;
      rect.setAttribute('x', xCoords[index]);
    });

    observer.observe(chartDiv, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  function getIntervals() {
    var intervals = [];
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(chartDiv.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(rect) {
      if ((rect.getAttribute('fill') === '#a52b0e') ||
          (rect.getAttribute('fill') === '#0c7112')) {
        intervals.push(rect);
      }
    });
    return intervals;
  }

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**note**: the offset used to move the x-coordinate (`22`) will remain constant,
so long as the size of the chart remains constant
and may need to be adjusted should the width of the chart change...

Comment: Thanks for the help!